# JNI exits with "undefined symbol"

Tags: java, c++, c, gcc, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use AES via the Crypto++ package from Java. Therefore I have two native methods `encrypt` and `decrypt` in my Java code which are then wrapped by C in order to access the C++ methods.
Running my C++ program from the command line works, but calling it from Java via JNI fails with an `undefined symbol` error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/yves/temp/lib/libCI3CppEncryptionTools.so: /home/yves/temp/lib/libCI3CppEncryptionTools.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN8CryptoPP6FilterE
```

I'm compiling it via:

```
g++ -c -Icryptopp562 -O3 -fwhole-program -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fPIC -fpermissive CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.cpp -Lcryptopp562 -lcryptopp
gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -O3 -fwhole-program -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libCI3CppEncryptionTools.so CI3CppEncryptionTools.c CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.o -Wl,--gc-sections
```

So first the C++ part and then combined with the C wrapper. `-fdata-sections`, `-ffunction-sections` and `-Wl,--gc-sections` were my attempt to strip dead code because I thought maybe JNI does not like unused or unreferenced code.

I checked if the symbol is undefined by using:

```
nm lib/libCI3CppEncryptionTools.so | grep _ZTIN8CryptoPP6FilterE
U _ZTIN8CryptoPP6FilterE
```

And yes, it is. But why is my C++ command line program working? Checking this yields the same result.

I also looked the symbol up:

```
c++filt _ZTIN8CryptoPP6FilterE
typeinfo for CryptoPP::Filter
```

The header for `CryptoPP::Filter` is included. I'm curious why it says `U` when checking for the symbol.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause the problem or where to look next to solve the problem? Any hints/insights are highly welcome!

Comment: The JNI entry points normally aren't referenced by your library, so if you tell GCC to remove unused symbols won't it just remove them?

Comment: This might be the case, but even if I remove these arguments passed to GCC it still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always forgot to link the Crypto++ library in the second step (actually I did it in the first step, which was complete nonsense). Those two commands compile the library a-ok!

```
g++ -c -Icryptopp562 -O3 -fPIC -fpermissive CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.cpp
gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -O3 -shared -fPIC -o libCI3CppEncryptionTools.so CI3CppEncryptionTools.c CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.o -lcryptopp
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile your CI3CppEncryptionTools.c first, then link its .o into the .so.  You are linking the .c

Edit:  Statically link your cryptocpp library into your shared library via : `-Wl,--whole-archive libcryptocpp.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive`

```
gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -O3 -fwhole-program -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libCI3CppEncryptionTools.so CI3CppEncryptionTools.c CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.o -Wl,--whole-archive libcryptocpp.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--gc-sections
```

Comment: Hm, shouldn't gcc first compile the .c and then pass the resulting .o and the one passed to the linker?

Comment: @yvesonline When you run the command, do you see it compiling the .c?  Your nm command is telling you the function is Undefined, so its clearly not compiling and including the code.

Comment: The mentioned function resides in the Crypto++ library. And yes, the .c gets compiled.

Comment: @yvesonline Since that's the case, it looks like your cryptopp library is a static library.  You will need to statically link it when you make your .so

Comment: actually, I compiled the Crypto++ library as a shared library... because I want an overall shared library which I can access with JNI. But you are right, I recognized the solution a few minutes myself, of course I have to link the Crypto++ library in the second step.